# Tensor product dimension problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

Im trying to show that if   $T$ and  $T'$ are tensors of $(r1,s1)$type and $(r2,s2)$type respectively, then the tensor product: $T\otimes T' $ is a $(r1+r2,s1+s2)$ tensor. So far I got this but I don't know how to continue :

1.) we have the expansion of the tensors:

$T = {T_{i1,i2,...,is1}}^{j1,j2,..,jr1}e_{i1}\otimes..\otimes e_{is1}\otimes e^{j1}\otimes...\otimes e^{jr1} $

$T'= {T'_{i1,i2,...,is2}}^{j1,j2,..,jr2}e_{i1}\otimes..\otimes e_{is2}\otimes e^{j1}\otimes...\otimes e^{jr2} $

2.) The tensor product is:

${T_{i1,i2,...,is1}}^{j1,j2,..,jr1}*{T'_{i1,i2,...,is2}}^{j1,j2,..,jr2}e_{i1}\otimes..\otimes e_{is1}\otimes e^{j1}\otimes...\otimes e^{jr1} \otimes e_{i1}\otimes..\otimes e_{is2}\otimes e^{j1}\otimes...\otimes e^{jr2}$

Now I know tensor product is assosiative but not conmmutative , so I think it should be exist a way to rearrange the tensors products in a way such that the basis of the product $T\otimes T' $ is:

$e_{i1}\otimes..\otimes e_{i(s1+s2)}\otimes e^{j1}\otimes...\otimes e^{j(r1+r2)}$

but I don't know how to justify it.

thank you very much if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the short answer is that this is a definition.

Starting with the definition of an $(r,s)$ Tensor:

Let $T_p(M)$ be defined as the tangent space of a manifold $M$ at point $p$ and let $T^*_p(M)$ be its dual space. Then a tensor of type $(r,s)$ at $p$ is a multilinear map

$T: T^*_p(M)^r \times T^*_p(M)^s \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now note that we could have just as well defined the tensor to have the domain

$T^*_p(M)^{r-1} \times T^*_p(M)^s \times T^*_p(m)$.

Intuitively this does not change the object we have as the spaces are isomorphic and this basically just changes the order you input the objects into your multilinear function but nothing else. Think of taking a function  $ f(x,y) = x +y $ instead of taking  $ g(y,x) = y + x $. Not here it is obvious to see that these are the same functions even though their arguments are switched. The same holds for the tensor and as such you might see that intuitively your result is the correct one up to an isomorphism shuffling around spaces.

So how do we make this precise in the case at hand? We just define our tensor product to have this property i.e. if $A$ is an $(r,s)$ tensor and $B$ is a $(q,p)$ tensor we define the $(r+q,s+p)$ tensor $( A \otimes B)$ such that for all sets of vectors $v_i \in T_p(M)$ and all sets of covectors $\eta_j \in T^*_p(M)$

$(A\otimes B)(\eta_1, ... \eta_r, \eta_{r+1},...\eta_{r+q},v_1,...v_{s+p}) \equiv  A(\eta_1,...\eta_r,v_1,...,v_s)B(\eta_{r+1},...,\eta_{r+q},v_{s+1},...v_{s+p})$.

Rewriting this definition using a basis as you did yields the desired result. Now you might say that this is just circumventing the original question but the idea here is that by the universal property of the tensor product as you define it more generally it can only ever be defined up to an isomorphism. As such you have to specify which of these tensor products you want to choose and the one I defined here is the natural choice in this case.